# Counting how many times an element occurs in the column of a data.frame

Tags: r, count, dataframe

Let's say I have a data.frame with a factor.

```
d = data.frame(f = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","d","d"))

  f
1 a
2 a
3 a
4 b
5 b
6 b
7 b
8 d
9 d
```

And I want to add a column telling me how many times an element occurs.

Like this

```
  f n
1 a 3
2 a 3
3 a 3
4 b 4
5 b 4
6 b 4
7 b 4
8 d 2
9 d 2
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table` like this:

```
d$n <- table(d$f)[d$f]
#  f n
#1 a 3
#2 a 3
#3 a 3
#4 b 4
#5 b 4
#6 b 4
#7 b 4
#8 d 2
#9 d 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also use some `plyr` functions - `join` & `ddply`

```
d <- data.frame(f = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","d","d"))   
d2 <- join(d, ddply(d, .(f), 'nrow'))
d2
  f nrow
1 a    3
2 a    3
3 a    3
4 b    4
5 b    4
6 b    4
7 b    4
8 d    2
9 d    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ave` and `length`:

```
> d$n <- as.numeric(ave(as.character(d$f), d$f, FUN = length))
> d
  f n
1 a 3
2 a 3
3 a 3
4 b 4
5 b 4
6 b 4
7 b 4
8 d 2
9 d 2
```

With the "data.table" package, you might do something like:

```
library(data.table)
D <- data.table(d)
D[, n := as.numeric(.N), by = f]
```